# Toyota auris 2010 stalls when you remove oil cap while engine is idling

Tags: engine, oil, stall, pcv-valve

I was inspecting a used Toyota Auris (2009-2010). I turned the engine on and with the car idling I removed the oil cap from the engine. The car stalled within seconds and the engine almost shut down.
I have read several websites. Half of the people argue that this is normal because the sensors cannot meter and adjust the air/fuel mix. Other people say that the engine and / or the PCV probably have problem.
Has somebody replicated this? Do you have any views if it normal or an indication of a faulty engine?
My Toyota Corolla (2004) does not stall and continues running but I expect the technology is completely different.
Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!